# Installing Matlab on a Windows Docker

Tags: c#, .net, windows, matlab, docker

Trying to install Matlab run time on a docker image along with the project I'm working on, the project is an engine that will run a variety of measurements based on what is given to it, many of these measurements use Matlab. When I run the docker though I get an error that the "MWArray assembly failed to be initialized" or that a matlab dll is missing.

I'm trying to run this in Docker for Windows due to a company requirement, and have been unable to successfully get the DockerFile to recognize the MCR. Below is the code that I've been playing with to get the MCR onto a docker.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

ADD http://ssd.mathworks.com/supportfiles/downloads/R2017b/deployment_files/R2017b/installers/win64/MCR_R2017b_win64_installer.exe C:\\MCR_R2017b_win64_installer.zip

# Line 3: Use PowerShell
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Line 4: Unpack ZIP contents to installation folder
RUN Expand-Archive C:\\MCR_R2017b_win64_installer.zip -DestinationPath C:\\MCR_INSTALLER

# Line 5: Run the setup command for a non-interactive installation of MCR
RUN Start-Process C:\MCR_INSTALLER\bin\win64\setup.exe -ArgumentList '-mode silent', '-agreeToLicense yes' -Wait

# Line 6: Remove ZIP and installation folder after setup is complete
RUN Remove-Item -Force -Recurse C:\\MCR_INSTALLER, C:\\MCR_R2017b_win64_installer.zip

WORKDIR /app
COPY /Project/bin/Debug/*.dll ./
COPY /Project/bin/Debug/Project.exe .
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\app\\Project.exe"]
```

Edit: I think I've found a working solution, following the idea from the other anwser about the ltsc2019 not working with Matlab 2017b. The below code has worked with 2017b inside a docker.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809
```

Comment: Put the matlab dll in the project folder where the other .cs files are located.  Then in Project menu : Add Existing Items and browse for matlab dll.  The in Solution Explorer right click on dll and in properties select "Copy to Output Directory" which will add dll to project and will get installed automatically.

Comment: When you say the matlab dll, are you talking about all the dll's found in C:\Program Files\MATLAB?

Comment: No.  The program files folder is the runtime which must be installed on machine. 
 Matlab has a compiled option that allows you to create a dll (from .m file)  that will only execute when the runtime installed.  You need the compiled dll file in the c# folder where the c# executable is located.  The compiled dll will get installed on deploy machine when you run setup.exe. (or the installed).

Comment: In the path Solution/Project/bin/Debug/ I have the dll's that I want and the project.exe, I build the docker then run it. During the run  I get this error "Loading C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v93\bin\win64\matlab_startup_plugins\lmgrimpl\libmwlmgrimpl.dllfailed with error: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: The C# project is using .NET Framework 4.7.1, and is targeting x64.

Comment: The runtime library must be the same version of matlab that was used to compile the dll.  It looks like you installed Matlab Runtime v93.  Matlab often obsoletes old methods and adds new methods.  I suspect that you didn't load same run time version that was used to compile dll so one of the modules is different.  I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Server 2019 is not supported by MATLAB R2017b, and support for it was not introduced until MATLAB R2019a.

For MATLAB R2017b you’ll need Windows Server 2016.

That’s not to say there may not be other issues as well.

Comment: windows server 2019 is being run from a power script.  What do that have to do with calling a matlab dll from c#?

Comment: The OP is attempting to create a Docker container that is running Windows Server 2019 (that’s the ltsc-2019 base image), together with MATLAB Runtime R2017b (that’s the line with the MCR_R2017b installer). This version of MATLAB Runtime is not supported on this version of Windows.

Comment: @SamRoberts Running on server 2016 still produces the same error. `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016` produced: Fatal Internal Error: std::exception: Bundle#4 start failed: Loading C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v93\bin\win64\matlab_startup_plugins\lmgrimpl\libmwlmgrimpl.dllfailed with error: The specified module could not be found.