# Installing Matlab 9.8(R2020a)on a Windows Docker with base image aspnet:6.0.16-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

Tags: .net, docker, matlab, .net-core, .net-6.0

My project is running in windows container and is having base image **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.16-windowsservercore-ltsc2019**.  I am trying to add Matlab 9.8 in the container, but I am getting errors while trying to do it. I tried [Installing Matlab on a Windows Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116298/installing-matlab-on-a-windows-docker) but it's not working. Any solution to it? Or is it possible to manually install Matlab in container and extrac.t image out of it?

Comment: MathWorks support are likely a better bet on installation support, or you'll need to provide more self-contained (not just external links) detail in your question about what you've specifically done and why it's "not working"